# Proof of growth of two increasing function

Tags: limits, functions, infinite-product

Suppose that we have functions $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ and both of them are increasing and both of them don't converge to the constant number and domain of them is Natural numbers and always they are positive. Also suppose that
$$\lim \frac{\log g(n)}{\log f(n)} = 0 \text{ for } n \rightarrow \infty$$

How to prove that: $\lim \frac{g(n)}{f(n)} = 0 \text{ for } n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: I like this question; I don't want to see it closed. Please add your own thoughts to avoid this

Comment: One idea to prove this problem is using Hopital rule but it does't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $g\left(n\right)$ and $f\left(n\right)$ tend to $+\infty$.
Write 
$$
\log g\left(n\right)=\log f\left(n\right)\varepsilon\left(n\right),
$$
where $\varepsilon\left(n\right)\rightarrow0$ . Then
\begin{align*}
g\left(n\right) & =\exp\left(\log f\left(n\right)\varepsilon\left(n\right)\right)=\exp\left(\log f\left(n\right)+\log f\left(n\right)\varepsilon\left(n\right)-\log f\left(n\right)\right)\\
 & =f\left(n\right)\exp\left(\log f\left(n\right)\left(\varepsilon\left(n\right)-1\right)\right).
\end{align*}
Now $\log f\left(n\right)\left(\varepsilon\left(n\right)-1\right)\rightarrow-\infty$,
hence its exponential tends to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it is correct. If $g\left(n\right)$ increases to 1
and $f\left(n\right)$ increases to $2$, then 
$$
\frac{\log\left(g\left(n\right)\right)}{\log\left(f\left(n\right)\right)}\rightarrow0,
$$
but 
$$
\frac{g\left(n\right)}{f\left(n\right)}\rightarrow\frac{1}{2}.
$$

Comment: One thing i missed to mention is that both function don't converge to the constant number. Thanks for correction.